# Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component - React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation for my React Native app, and my view looks something like this:

```
root/
  game1
    Details game1
  game2
    Details game2
  game3
    Details game3
```

I have a stack navigation, and when I mount one of the games I have axios retrieving some data, like teamname and some information about the teams in each game. Whenever I unmount and enter then mount a new game, I get this error: `Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component` and my images loads VERY slow. I don't have any code in componentWillmount/didmount because my screenprops is an empty string while mounting and then turns into an object when mounting is complete. I've tried to console.log during different lifecycles and it only says it's an object when mounting is complete.

What usually creates this problem, and how can I fix it?

I have a component that looks like this

```
class Blinking extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showText: true
    };
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { showText: !previousState.showText };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ opacity: this.state.showText ? 1 : 0 }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Blinking;
```

I assume that one of the issues is that the interval continues when I unmount that component.

Comment: It is most probably due to react trying to render/setstate on component which you have unmounted. This happens when you call an Async function, and while waiting for its response, you unmounts the component, after unmounting the component, the server response is received, and react tries to set that response to an unmounted component, and since it is unmounted, it gives you the above warning.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense. However, I don't get this error until unmount and then mount the same component, just with different data. Could it still be the same reason?

Comment: Maybe the component you just unmounted might have had an incomplete async task which triggered after unmounting the component. There might be other reasons too.

Comment: I think I found the reason. I had so many setstates, which made it re-render and triggering after unmounting. I forgot that setstate is an async function.
Thanks for your answer. Just curios, do you have any clue or opinion on how many setStates you should have in one component? do you even use it?

Comment: We have integrated redux in our App, but we only make use of redux whenever it is absolutely necessary. We mostly make use of component level state and use setState for it. setState, like you said, is an async function and you can pass a callback function to setState by passing the function as second argument for the setState.

Comment: I have the same warnings coming up in my app when going back and forth between screens rapidly. There are many workarounds for this, and all of them simply check of the component is still mounted using various ways, and calls setState only if it mounted.